# Enabling the CORS filter for Lagom Java

Tags: angularjs, playframework, cors, lagom

I have followed the instruction of [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter) in order to access localhost:9000 (Lagom GateWay where my microservices are running)  from localhost:3000 (where my angular front-end is running). but still I face:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/myservice. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

doe anyone have a sample or project that enabling CORS works there?

Comment: do you see the Access Control headers in the response header, when you open the URL in a separate browser window?

Comment: @Sreekanth  I am using PostMan and in GET method with postman I have following in header:
Content-Length →145
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 27 Oct 2016 18:14:09 GMT

Comment: If you dont see the Access headers, it means, they are not being set. When you set the headers and correct and are being applied, you shouldnt run into this problem. If I were you, I ll check and get the response headers in the request first, before trying to consume

Comment: yes exactly, and my question is how to set the headers in server? the instruction playframework seems does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quote from James Roper He publish in the Lagom google user group

The simplest way to get CORS working in Lagom is to use Play's CORS support (Lagom is built on top of Play):

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter

Comment: And question in the group was asked by me :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a Filters class which extends the Play class

```
public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {

  @Inject
  public Filters(CORSFilter corsFilter) {
    super(corsFilter);
  }
}
```

and add conf to include that filter

```
play.http.filters = "io.my.http.Filters"
```

you may also need to configure the filter

```
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of others working with Angular 4 front-end and lagom backend project. I have managed to solve this way.

*I added this line below in my build.sbt in both api and impl *

libraryDependencies += filters

*In my impl directory, i created folder filters and added the code below*

```
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.HttpFilters;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    CORSFilter corsFilter;

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[]{corsFilter.asJava()};
    }
}
```

*In my application.conf i added the code that follows*

```
play.filters.hosts {
  # Allow requests to example.com, its subdomains, and localhost:9000.
  allowed = ["localhost:5000", "localhost:9000"]
}

play.http.filters = "filters.Filters"

play.filters.cors {
  # Filter paths by a whitelist of path prefixes
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]

  # The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

After this, i restarted my lagom microservices and it worked like a charm.