# Using jersey filters in Lagom

Tags: lagom

Read the documents but couldn't find support for using jersey filters (ContainerRequestFilters, Filters etc).

Can someone please some examples of using Jersey filters in lagom?

Answer (score 2):

Lagom isn't based on Jersey, so you can't use Jersey filters directly.

Lagom provides its own APIs for transforming requests and responses.

See [Header Filters](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/HeaderFilters.html) and [Service call composition](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ServiceImplementation.html#Service-call-composition) for examples.

Comment: You can also use Play filters such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291472/enabling-the-cors-filter-for-lagom-java/42443930#42443930